# Find the probability that the connection of two vertices of a rectangular prism are skew.

Tags: probability, geometry, 3d

R denotes a rectangular prism, S denotes the set of lines L where L passes through two of the vertices of R. If two random lines are chosen from S, what is the probability that these two lines are skew?

I know that there are 28 possible lines in S. I tried to use combinatorics to solve this, but I got confused because there was repetitions.

Comment: Probably easier if you choose the lines in order so $28\times 27$ equally probable ways of choosing them. There are three types of line: edge, face diagonal and interior diagonal, and each type has a number of parallel lines depending on its type.  So deal with the three cases and find how many skew lines it has.

Comment: @Henry I understand that method. However, won't there be repetition? Do you think there is a more algebraic solution to this?

Comment: Yes if "skew" means not intersecting; no if skew means not intersecting and not parallel.  The only repetition comes from choosing the same pair of lines in a different order, and that happens in every one of the equally likely possibilities so is not a problem - you can ignore the issue